# Бот присылает одну картинку вместо разных

Tags: python, telebot

Задача:
Внимательно изучите API https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/
Необходимо написать бота, который по команде /coffee будет отправлять случайное фото кофе.
Подскажите пожалуйста почему картинка одна и та же?

```
import telebot # Импортирует библиотеки telebot.
from bot_token import TOKEN # Импортирует TOKEN из файла bot_token.
import requests # Импортирует библиотеки requests.

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) # Создает экземпляр класса TeleBot.

@bot.message_handler(commands=['coffee']) # Обработчик реагирует на команду coffee
def send_coffee(message):
    r = requests.get('https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/random.json')
    url = 'https://coffee.alexflipnote.dev/random'
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, url)
    
if __name__ == '__main__': # Бот постоянно запрашивает обновления сервера.
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Ну так ты не используешь url из ответа... Чего ещё ожидать

Comment: bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, r.json()['file'])